# Specify framework versions with dotnet new angular

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I am trying to create an angular project in VS code on linux. I want to use framework version 2.2 (which is installed) but I *also* have a preview of 3.0 installed for another project that requires it.

When I run `dotnet new angular` it uses 3.0 by default. Ok fine, I'll go and manually edit the csproj. Problem is, there are dependencies, specifically

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.0.0-preview4-19216-03" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions" Version="3.0.0-preview4-19216-03" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I assumed I could just change the versions on both deps but I was wrong. It seems `NewtonsoftJson` doesn't even exist for version prior to 3.0.

At this point, I'm not sure what the best approach is. I don't want to have to dig around for and manually add the right dependencies. I was *really* hoping to use the dotnet cli to get my project created.

So how can I specify the framework version for `dotnet new`? If I can't, how am I expected to create a working angular.js project via the dotnet CLI?

Comment: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` is probably new for .net core 3. Have you tried specifying the framework with the `dotnet` command? See [dotnet new](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new?tabs=netcore21#template-options)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to create a global.json file in the directory *before* running `dotnet new` with these contents:

```
{
    "sdk": {
      "version": "2.2.105"
    }
  }
```

Comment: dotnet --list-sdks will get you a list of sdks on your machine to choose from. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json will get you the matching rules.